# How to compare parent and child record in nested array?

Tags: javascript

I am having a nodes like below in hierarchical structure :

```
Node - 1
     Node-1-1
       Node-1-1-1
```

Now I want to check whether connections is define or not between parent and child nodes.

Connections between parent and child is define like below for eg between Node-1 and  Node-1-1 :

```
"connections": {
          "joins": [
            {
              "parent": "Node-1",
              "child": "Node-1-1"
            }
          ]
        }
```

If there exist at least 1 connection (**1 record in joins property of connections**) between parent and child nodes then it's fine else I want to show alert to user and would like to return from the iterate function immediately on encounter of no connection between nodes.

So unless and until I get a response from iterate function(i.e iterate function is not completed) I don't want to increment my id that is why I am passing callback to iterate function and would like to return response.

As there is no connections between Node-1-1 and Node-1-1-1 so I would like to show alert to user because there is no record in joins property of connections.

But problem is I am not getting how to compare every parent and child nodes and how to manage this callback in recursive structure.

```js
var records = [
  {
    "name": "Node-1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node-1-1",
        "isParent": false,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "Node-1-1-1",
            "isParent": false,
            "nodes": [
              
            ],
            "connections": {
              "joins": []
            }
          }
        ],
        "connections": {
          "joins": [
            {
              "parent": "Node-1",
              "child": "Node-1-1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "isParent": true
  }
];


function CheckConnections(){
     var id=0;
     iterate(records,
                function (valid) {
                   if(valid)
                   {
                      id = id + 1;
                      console.log(id);
                   }
                  else
                      alert("please define connections")
                }
            ); 
     
}

function iterate(nodes,callback)
{
   var connectionDefine = false;
   
   callback(false);
}
```

```html
<input type="button"  value="Check Connections"  onclick="CheckConnections()">
```

Comment: So, you want a check that makes sure all objects in the `nodes` array is also present in the `connections` array, in the form of a parent-child connection?

How would the structure look if a node had more than one child?
How would the structure look if `CheckConnections()` were to return true(no error)?

Comment: @mTv : each parent will have only 1 child and if there is no error then simply it should return callback(true) else callback(false)

Comment: Do you need to just check if there is a node with an empty `joins` property or can it be non-empty but somehow invalid?

Comment: @vassiliskrikonis:I just want to check if there is a node with empty joins property but only in case of parent and child node.so for eg.Node-1-1-1 is child of Node-1-1 right so i want to check that there is connection between this 2 nodes or not.

Comment: for what do you need `id`? should the result be only `true` or `false`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Actually i am doing some operation on that id so unless and untill i dont get confirmation that all connections between parent and child are define i wont increment that id variable and infact would like to give alert to user that please define connections.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah basically the result should be true/false along with the 2 nodes name between whom connections is not there so that i can show that 2 nodes name in alert to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a recursive function to do this, function takes two arguments-- node and its parent. At each recursion check if there are joins available and parent in joins is same as parent that was passed during recursion. And child in joins should be current node name. Something like this:

```js
var records = [
  {
    "name": "Node-1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node-1-1",
        "isParent": false,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "Node-1-1-1",
            "isParent": false,
            "nodes": [
              
            ],
            "connections": {
              "joins": []
            }
          }
        ],
        "connections": {
          "joins": [
            {
              "parent": "Node-1",
              "child": "Node-1-1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "isParent": true
  }
];


function CheckConnections(){
     var id=0;
     var inValidNodes = [];
     records.forEach(function(node){
       inValidNodes = checkValidConnections(node, null);
       if (inValidNodes.length > 0)
           return;
     });

     if(inValidNodes.length === 0)
     {
          id = id + 1;
          console.log(id);
      } else {
         alert("please define connections " + inValidNodes);
      }
}
function checkValidConnections(node, parent){
       var nodeName = node.name;
       if(!node.isParent){
          var currentParentCondition = node.connections.joins.length > 0 &&
                                   node.connections.joins[0].parent === parent &&
                                   node.connections.joins[0].child === nodeName;
          if (!currentParentCondition)
              return [parent, nodeName];
       }

       if (node.nodes.length > 0){
          return checkValidConnections(node.nodes[0], nodeName);
       } else{
          return [];
       }           
}
```

```html
<input type="button"  value="Check Connections"  onclick="CheckConnections()">
```

Comment: Why you have pass Node[0] i.e hardcoded index for node.shouldnt it be nodes?

Answer (score 2):

The following recursive solution will show you the error on the first missing connection relation encountered. I added comments so that you can track what happens.

It does not inspect all the connections: when it finds one that is properly made between child and parent, it breaks fast to move onto the next nodes.

Basically it consists in searching, for each child node, if the connections for the current parent/child relation are properly recorded. It should work with any number of child nodes / nested levels.

```
var records = [{"name":"Node-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1","isParent":false,"nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1-1","isParent":false,"nodes":[],"connections":{"joins":[]}}], "connections":{"joins":[{"parent":"Node-1","child":"Node-1-1"}]}}],"isParent":true}];

function connections_control(records, parent = undefined) {
    // Browse the nodes list
    for (var node of records) {
        // Control if the keys we need do exist
        if (parent && node.connections && node.connections.joins) {
            var found = false;
            // Search in connections the current relation parent/child
            for (var connection of node.connections.joins) {
                if (connection.parent == parent && connection.child == node.name) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                // We checked all connections, but we did not find our current relation!
                console.log('Warning: Broken connection between parent node '+parent+' and child node '+node.name);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (node.nodes) {
            // The current node becomes parent, start again with the inner nodes list
            connections_control(node.nodes, node.name);
        }
    }
}

connections_control(records);
```

Note that on the first loop, which is taking your document at its root, there is no parent so there is no search for connections.

**Execution:**

```
nodejs childs.js
Warning: Broken connection between parent node Node-1-1 and child node Node-1-1-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive approach for calling `check` with an array and the parent name.

Inside, the first object of `connections.joins` is tested.

The result is either `undefined`, which means all connection are defined, or you get an object with the first missing connection.

The check takes the parent name from the calling object.

(With this, a check like `!o.isParent ...` could be omitted and just a check for `parent` could be used instead, because in the first call `parent` is undefined, which would prevent checking.)

```js
function check(array, parent) {
    var missing;
    array.some(function (o) {
        var j = o.connections && o.connections.joins && o.connections.joins[0];
        if (!o.isParent && (!j || j.parent !== parent || j.child !== o.name)) {
            return missing = { parent: parent, child: o.name };
        }
        if (o.nodes) {
            return missing = check(o.nodes, o.name);
        }                
    });
    return missing;
}

var records0 = [{ name: "Node-1", nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1", isParent: false, nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1-1", isParent: false, nodes: [], connections: { joins: [{ parent: "Node-1-1", child: "Node-1-1-1" }] } }], connections: { joins: [{ parent: "Node-1", child: "Node-1-1" }] } }], isParent: true }],
    records1 = [{ name: "Node-1", nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1", isParent: false, nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1-1", isParent: false, nodes: [], connections: { joins: [ /* missing */ ] } }], connections: { joins: [{ parent: "Node-1", child: "Node-1-1" }] } }], isParent: true }];

console.log(check(records0)); // undefined, nothing missing
console.log(check(records1)); // missing { parent: "Node-1-1", child: "Node-1-1-1" }
```

A slightly better data structure would help, if `connections.joins` is just an object and not an array, which needs iteration to check if the given parent/child match.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but there can be multiple connections between parent and child nodes that is why i have taken joins as an array.Now does it make sense mam??

Comment: @Learning, 
please add some use cases to the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: mam is this line checking each and every record inside joins array ?? :  if (!o.isParent && !o.connections.joins.some(function (p) { return p.parent === parent && p.child === o.name; }))

Comment: it does. the `some` method iterates and checks if a valid parent/children combo is around.

Comment: Mam but i just want to check only first record of joins array.so will this work?? : !o.connections.joins[0].some(function (p)

Comment: @lerning, now it check only the first item of `joins`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149719/discussion-between-learning-and-nina-scholz).