# Why my 2 object deep comparison is failing?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to compare 2 objects using deep comparison and while comparison i want to ignore some properties.

My comparison is successful when I have those ignore properties on both the side of object.

But I am getting problem when I have 1 property missing in 2nd object which I want to ignore.

In my objA and objB, I want to ignore isParent and location property but as I don't have location property in objB, my object comparison is failing.

But I don't understand why I am getting false as I have specified location property to ignore.

```js
var objA = {
  isParent: true,
  foo: {
    location: "abc",
    bar: "foobar"
  }
};

var objB = {
  isParent: false,
  foo: {
    bar: "foobar"
  }
};

var comparator = function(left, right, key) {
  if (key === 'isParent' || key === 'location') return true;//ignore isParent and location property while comparing 2 object
  else return undefined;              
}

var isEqual = _.isEqualWith(objA, objB, comparator);

console.log(isEqual); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your code when key == 'foo' comparator returns undefined so the final result becomes false. You have to deal with all true cases, not only with the skip cases.

Comment: @acampos When i have same amount of properties in both the object then my comparision is successfull.

Comment: It's correct but you have to implement all the right cases. You don't have to return undefined all the cases apart off when key is equal to that

Comment: @acampos Can you please add some more details in to it or may be in the form of answer would help more

Comment: I think it is better if you go as @Vanojx1 say by using _.omit() . More elegant and easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) function to ignore unwanted properties then compare

```js
var objA = {
  isParent: true,
  foo: {
    location: "abc",
    bar: "foobar"
  }
};

var objB = {
  isParent: false,
  foo: {
    bar: "foobar"
  }
};

var isEqual = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(objA, ['isParent', 'foo.location']), 
  _.omit(objB, ['isParent', 'foo.location'])
);

console.log(isEqual); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If `foo` has another object(*say `bar`*) in it which has `location`, you will add another line `_.omit(obj, 'foo.bar.location')`?

Comment: Yes omit function needs the path of each ignored property

Comment: But omits has a performance problem of creating copy of those ignore property while comparing 2 objects :)

Comment: @Vanojx1 This will bind the keys to structure. 1 benefit of this would be if you wish to ignore at some place. But if you wish to ignore at all places, it will become difficult to keep track, as OP has commented that the object is big

Comment: To handle performance issue i need more information about your code logic... in general my anwer provide a solution using only lodash builtin functions. The question dont talk about ignoring nested properties by name.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own compare function:

#### Logic:

- Create a function that takes 2 objects that will be compared and an array(`ignoreKeys`) of keys that are to be ignored.
- Get all keys from both object, merge them and then filter them into a new variable (*say `keys`*).

  - If the current key exists in `keys`, ignore it.
  - If the current key exists in `ignoreKeys`, ignore it
  - Else push it.
- Now loop over these keys and check for comparison:

  - If current value is of type 'object', use recursion and start the process again.
  - Else, compare the values and return the comparison.

Since this has to be done for all the keys in `keys`, you can use `Array.every`.

**Sample**

```js
function compareObject(obj1, obj2, ignoreProps){
  var temp = Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2)).sort();
  var keys = temp.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if(p.indexOf(c) < 0 && ignoreProps.indexOf(c) < 0) {
      p.push(c);
    }
    return p;
  }, []);
  
  return keys.every(function(key){
    var t1 = typeof(obj1[key])
    var t2 = typeof(obj2[key])
    if(t1 === t1) {
      switch(t1) {
        case 'object': 
          if(obj1[key] !== null && obj2[key] !== null)
            return compareObject(obj1[key], obj2[key], ignoreProps);
          else
            return obj1[key] === obj2[key];
        default: return obj1[key] === obj2[key];
      }
    }
  })
}

var objA = {
  isParent: true,
  foo: {
    location: "abc",
    bar: "foobar",
    test: {
      location: 'bla',
      test1: {
        location: 'bla bla',
        value: null
      }
    }
  }
};

var objB = {
  isParent: false,
  foo: {
    bar: "foobar",
    test: {
      location: 'new',
      test1: {
        location: 'new new',
        value: null
      }
    }
  }
};

var ignoreProperties = ['isParent', 'location'];

console.log(compareObject(objA, objB, ignoreProperties));
```

Comment: Ok let say inside foo object i have 1 another object which again have location property which i want to ignore 
so now i have to adjust code accordingly as because i have this location property at lots of place which i want to ignore

Comment: Sorry i was just trying to understand your approach as because i am having a huge object with lots of properties and this location and some other properties which i want to ignore are at lots of place so

Comment: @Learning I have already explained my algo in answer. Still, if you have any queries, feel free to clarify it. Also, you don't have to apologize. We all are learning. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but 1 question related to performance like my solution(lodash) vs your solution
for deep object comparision.Can you please comment something on this?

Comment: @Learning I'm have not used lodash mush, so it would be difficult to answer it. But we can safely assume that lodash would perform better. Since it is a library, they put lot of focus on performance. That said, I do not think this difference will be big and will have impact on application, unless you have a real-time blotter like application.

Comment: I am getting error on first line with my data structure:Cannot convert undefined or null to object.My structure looks this this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037809/how-to-compare-parent-and-child-record-in-nested-array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155567/discussion-between-learning-and-rajesh).

Answer (score 1):

You could take all keys of the given objects and iterate and check if either

- is a key of a no value check (ignore),
- has same values or
- both values are truthy and objects and the call of check returns a truthy value.

The keys of the properties to ignore are collected in an object.

```js
function check(o, p) {
    var keys = [...new Set(Object.keys(o).concat(Object.keys(p)))];

    return keys.every(k => noValueCheck[k]
        || o[k] === p[k]
        || o[k] && p[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && typeof p[k] === 'object' && check(o[k], p[k])
    );
}

var noValueCheck = { isParent: true, location: true },
    objA = { isParent: true, foo: { location: "abc", bar: "foobar" } },
    objB = { isParent: false, foo: { bar: "foobar" } };

console.log(check(objA, objB));
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Let me test this abit